# Word for "in the ongoing sense"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase to distinguish between imminently and in general? For example to differentiate between:

> I'm dying (as in imminently)

And:

> I'm dying (as in all living things come to an end)

Now I realize that the latter is incredibly uncommon, but sometimes people mean that, and there's other cases:

> You need to hand in your homework (as in the most recent assignment)

Vs:

> You need to hand in your homework (all homework in general)

Or do you just need to rely on context?

(Unsure if the `tenses` tag applies, will remove if necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are words to help with such things, and you've used some already: *imminently*, *eventually*, *continuously*, *generally*, and so on. These are sometimes called ***[adverbs of time](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/adverbs-time.htm)***.

You might even get away with ***[ongoingly](http://There%20are%20words%20to%20help%20with%20such%20things,%20and%20you've%20used%20some%20already:%20imminently,%20eventually,%20continuously,%20generally,%20and%20so%20on.%20Maybe%20even%20ongoingly%20(en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ongoingly))***, defined as:

> In an ongoing fashion.

In addition to *ongoingly*, *continuously*, and *generally*, other adverbs of time encoding indefinite but ongoing frequency include: *regularly*, *habitually*, and *normally*.